# What's best way to find files in a directory | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I need to read all the files in the directory using php. So I need return like this

```
array(
        'content_type' => 'application/zip', 
        'suggested_name' => 'this_is_example.zip', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/this_is_example.zip'
    ),
```

My generate file like this:

```
$download_list = array();
    if(is_array($PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS)) {
        foreach ($PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS as $key => $download) {
            // Create a new key
            $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);
            // get download link and file size
            $download_link = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . DOWNLOAD_PATH . "?key=" . $new . "&i=" . $key; 
            $filesize = human_filesize(filesize($download['protected_path']), 2);
            $filename = ($download['suggested_name']);
            // Add to the download list
            $download_list[] = array(
                'download_link' => $download_link,
                'filename' => $filename,
                'filesize' => $filesize
            );

            /*
             *  Create a protected directory to store keys in
             */
            if(!is_dir('history')) {
                mkdir('keys');
                $file = fopen('history/.htaccess','w');
                fwrite($file,"Generator");
                fclose($file);
            }

            /*
             *  Write the key key to the keys list
             */
            $file = fopen('history/keys','a');
            fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
```

Now everything is working, but I have to enter these files myself before run it. How can I publish all the files from directory?
Now I have like this:

```
$PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS = array(
    array(
        'content_type' => 'application/png', 
        'suggested_name' => 'example.png', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/example.png'
    ),
    array(
        'content_type' => 'application/txt', 
        'suggested_name' => 'this_is_example.txt', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/this_is_example.txt'
    ),
    array(
        'content_type' => 'application/zip', 
        'suggested_name' => 'this_is_example.zip', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/this_is_example.zip'
    ),
    array(
        'content_type' => 'application/rar', 
        'suggested_name' => 'this_is_example.rar', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/this_is_example.rar'
    ),
    array(
        'content_type' => 'application/docx', 
        'suggested_name' => 'this_is_example.docx', 
        'protected_path' => 'download/this_is_example.docx'
    )
);
```

I tried with glob(), scandir() and readdir(), but I could not get the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: How far have you got?  Add the code so far and people may be able to adjust it to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but have a try like this.

```
<?php
$directory = 'download';
$PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS = [];
foreach (glob($directory."/*") as $filename) {
    $PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS[]['content_type'] = mime_content_type($filename);
    $PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS[]['suggested_name'] = $filename;
    $PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS[]['protected_path'] = "$directory/$filename";
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($PROTECTED_DOWNLOADS);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: If only files with a specific file ending are desired, it is possible to use `glob("download/*.{txt,png,zip,doc,docx,tar}", GLOB_BRACE)`. The `GLOB_BRACE` is important. Of course it is possible to build the file ending expression dynamically from an array as well.